# What does it mean for a set $A$ to be computably enumerable in another set $B$?

Tags: notation, computational-complexity, computability

In my introductory computability class I keep seeing the phrase set $A$ computably enumerable IN set $B$?

I don't want a definition of computably enumerable, I know what that is, and there are a lot of answers for that. I purely want to know why one set is somehow being INSIDE another one means.

An example of the phrasing being used when talking about Turing degree:

> (iii) A degree **a** is *computably enumerable in* degree **b** (**a** is *c.e. in* **b**) if there exists some set $A \in \mathbf a$ that is c.e. in some set $B \in \mathbf b$.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

"In" here doesn't mean "inside of" - it's more in the spirit of "in *a parameter for*." Really, the phrase we should use in place of "in" is "**relative to**" - if you're familiar with [Turing reducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction), saying "$A$ is c.e. in $B$" is analogous to saying "$A$ is computable relative to $B$," or "$A\le_TB$."

If you're not familiar with Turing reducibility, we're talking about [oracle machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine). Recall that $A$ is c.e. if $A$ is the set of inputs on which some Turing machine halts; well, $A$ is c.e. *in $B$* if $A$ is the set of inputs on which some *oracle* Turing machine halts *when given $B$ as an oracle*. More snappily:

> "$A$ is c.e. in $B$" means that *using $B$ as an oracle* we can computably enumerate $A$.

For example, it's easy to see that $A$ is always c.e. in $\overline{A}$; by contrast, the complement of a c.e. set is c.e. iff it is computable. More interestingly, we can [relativize the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump) and this gives us - for any $B$ - a "maximally complicated" set $A$ which is c.e. in $B$, analogously to how the Halting Problem itself is the "maximally complicated" c.e. set.

Comment: I like to express this in terms of definability, as $\Sigma^0_1$ definable in the structure $(\mathbb N,+,\times,0,1,<,B)$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I also like that, but I don't know if the OP's familiar with $\Sigma^0_1$ definability and its relationship with computability theory.

Comment: For those of us following from the peanut gallery who haven't studied this stuff for a very long time, computable is the same as recursive and c.e. is the same as recursively enumerable?

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, [and occasionally pineapple](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m773-07/pineapp.pdf).